# Are Nameless ______ safe to sell?

Tags: witch-and-hundred-knight

I've been picking up things like Nameless Bones and Nameless Pumpkins from spots where I have been getting Fools Rocks from.

Fools Rocks are needed for upgrading equipment in Metalia's house, but at times I question if I actually need all these Nameless items. I always seem to side on hording them in case I need them later for something, but I'm not sure this is necessary.

Are Nameless ______ safe to sell? I won't need them later in-game for anything?

NOTE: this is the Revival Edition i'm playing on the PS4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to multiple posts [such as this one](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/150091-the-witch-and-the-hundred-knight-revival-edition/73438343), there's no need to hold onto those "nameless" items-- you can just go ahead and sell them.

> Sell those for $$. Only useful item from searching is fools rock. :)
>
> Just swag, like garbage. Fool's rocks are actually a bit more useful than in the PS3 version, since they can be used to level up armor now, and are, to my knowledge, the only way to do so.

[Here's](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/644717-the-witch-and-the-hundred-knight/73536130) another thread saying the same thing (only keep Fool's Rocks):

> Pretty much all the loot items you get from searching and capturing enemies are meant just to be sold. The only things you should keep are Fool's Rocks since they are used to level up your weapons.